# How to convert a float value(got from a JSON) to string in php maintaining "trailing zeros"?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I've a JSON (i.e. a javascript object).

I have a page that get the content of the JSON (i.e. a set of fields,array and objects).

Some of these fields are **float** values. The **number of DECIMAL DIGITS** depends on the specific field.

My question is: **how do I print the WHOLE number as it was a STRING**"?

Example:

```
   12.35 --> print: 12.35 (but this is ok,a floatval() works!)
   12.0 --> print: 12.0 (this is NOT ok,because floatval() prints just "12")
   12.00 --> print: 12.00 (this is NOT ok,because floatval() prints just "12")
```

Of course I tried to print the value **without casting**(i.e. without using floatval() ). But is seems that the **cast** is done **"implicity"** by PHP.

And of course if there are not 0 (e.g. "12") **no 0s should be printed**

Thank you in advance for any tip.

Comment: Numbers are numbers; they don't track how many zeroes they were created with.  It sounds like you should be using strings.

Comment: I agree with you. But the json is not created (nor mantained) by me. And I need a way to read the numbers as strings

Comment: I don't understand the question, you're not describing the actual intended result properly. Also, yes PHP does a lot of implicit casting, that's the drawback of a weak-typed language.

Comment: @Niels Simply if I have a number (as it is written in the JSON file) and I want to print it as string (including trailing 0s)

Comment: Is'nt the JSON a string to begin with, so just stop using floatval? You could always cast it `(string)$variable` !

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/sprintf http://php.net/number_format   trailing zeroes is a DISPLAY problem.

Comment: @adeneo the "float fields" in the JSON are NUMBERS. NOT strings (they don't have " "). So even without the cast is implicit. Marc B Already tried,but the number of decimals digits is not fixed

Comment: @dragonmnl in that case you can only fix it by parsing the string manually. If you have `{"string":"12.0","value":12.0}` it makes complete sense that `json_decode` will translate this as `["string":"12.0","value":12]` in PHP. You can only circumvent this by not using `json_decode`, which would completely defeat the point of having JSON to begin with if you're reinterpreting the data anyway.

Comment: ok @Niels you are right. I will do it manually!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
$a=(float)"12.00";
print number_format($a,2);
```